# Preventing Rails to reaload assets in popup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, popup, asset-pipeline

In my Rails 4 (with assets pipeline), I have a `Profile` page that allows user to open a popup by clicking a link.  My Javascript looks like this:

```
jQuery('.popupHolder').load($this.attr("href"), function () {do_something})
```

where href is defined as: `update_user_path` and attached to a `div` in my page.

My issue is:  when the Profile page is loaded, all assets are also loaded. When user clicks the link, the browser makes a request to `users_controller#update`, and thus load all the assets again.

(If the popup page was just a static html file, it would not reload assets).

How do I prevent Rails to reload assets in this case?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "reloading assets", do you mean that the HTML for the popup ends up including your site header and footer (so a whole page) rather than just an HTML snippet? If that's the case, you need to tell that controller action (`update`) not to load the layout. Put `render layout: false` or add `layout: false` to the hash passed to render, and your action will respond just with the HTML in the template and no surrounding layout.

There's some useful info about layouts and rendering in the Rails Guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: I meant all the assets (images, javascript files) are reloaded.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood what you meant by the page was reloading. It sounds like your jQuery code is not using AJAX, which is triggering a page reload. You need to trigger the content loading over AJAX and disable the standard link behavior. One way to do this is to make use of the Rails unobtrusive JavaScript (UJS) plugin and adding 'data-remote="true"' to the link tags that trigger the popup.